# Android Guaranteed Reference to a Contact

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-database

I have an app that needs to maintain persistent references to certain contacts on a device. I used to do this by storing `ContactsContract.Contact._ID`, but I've recently had issues where the `_ID` would change and I was no longer able to reference the contact.

I switched to using `ContactsContract.Contact.LOOKUP_KEY` which I understood would be a unique, constant way to reference a contact. However, I've gotten reports that some contacts on some devices have a `LOOKUP_KEY` of `null`.

Am I wrong in my understanding of `LOOKUP_KEY`?

1. Can it be null?
2. Can it change?
3. If yes to either 1 or 2, is there a guaranteed way to store a reference to a contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Contacts DB we have many tables where we save information related to a Contacts, such as `Contacts` , `Data` , `Mimetype` , `RawContacts` , `Accounts` etc.

The `ContactsContract.Contact._ID` changes when there is an update , merge or sync to the server , the `ContactsContract.Contact._ID` will change from time, you need to make use of `ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID` which will be unique and will not change until and unless there is deletion of contact.

ContactsContract.Contact.LOOKUP_KEY wiill not be changed until you join a contact with another or you separate a merged contacts. Or you can use  coloumn  "name_raw_contact_id" from Contacts table which will be same always and not change.

Comment: I cannot use `ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID`. Do you know if `ContactsContract.Contact.LOOKUP_KEY` is stable?

Comment: ContactsContract.Contact.LOOKUP_KEY wiill not be changed until you join a contact with another or you separate a merged contacts. Or you can use  coloumn  "name_raw_contact_id" from Contacts table which will be same.

Comment: Thanks! `NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID` looks interesting.

Comment: You're welcome , happy to help . I work on Conctacts app, lemme know if you hv ny queries